# Creating Relationship in PowerBI

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax, datamodel

I have to create a relationship, where both table have dates and measures. I created name bridge between two tables. if i pull by name it works, however, not with date, i am not able to create the relationship. Can you please help to create relation between dates, so that amount can be displayed by Name and date for amt_outstanding and Amt_received together. Below is the sample and outcome sample.

Thanks in Advance

[image: Sample Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have only one active relationship between two tables. So, if you are already having active relationship on Name, then the date based relationship will be inactive relationship. So, it is not working.

Btw, your model has to go for below changes:

1. Create a Date Dimension with the list of dates
2. Now, create relationship between individual fact tables and corresponding date dimension. Preferably, try to have a single Fact table with Amount_Recevied, Amount_Outstanding, as it will make the model much cleaner.

Now, if you are dragging and dropping the fields, they will work fine without issues.

Comment: Can i keep both tables and connect them with date dimension which i have. i am facing issue with dates table which i cant connect to both tables as they will become circular. Hope i am making sense

Comment: dont have circular relationship. Have just Date dimension and point that to two separate fact tables. one parent, two childern. You will not have circular

Comment: you can do either ways: one fact, one date dimension or one name dimension, one date dimension, two fact tables